# Can I negate this? Discrete Mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If I have a proposition saying that if this function F(n) "x^(n)-1" = a composite number, then "n" is also composite is not always true.

I want to say that if F is a composite number then n is not. So basically if P then not Q. This is proven to be very difficult as most numbers that I can do in my head adds up. Can I switch the role around?

Can I go from "If P then Not Q"
To
"If Not P, then Q"?

And if so ,is it done by just doing this?:
"Not (if P then Not Q)"?

Comment: The negation of "if P, then Q" is "P and not-Q". Thus, the negation of "if P, then not-Q" must be "P and Q".

Comment: But it seems to me that you have to negate a quantified statement : "for every $n$, if $x^{n-1}$ is Composite, then $n$ is Composite". In this case, the negation is "outside" the quantifier.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to MSE!

The implication $P\Rightarrow Q$ is logically equivalent to $\neg Q\Rightarrow \neg P$.
So ''if $F$ is composite, then $n$ is not composite" is equivalent to "if $n$ is composite, then $F$ is not composite''.